# how to open file sound wav in javascript

Tags: javascript, mp3

Following is js the code to open an .mp3 file which works

```
<script>
var audio = new Audio('Sound/Ring10.mp3');
audio.play();
</script>
```

What is the js code to open .wav file format?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
<script>
var audio = new Audio('Sound/Wavefile.wav');
audio.play();
</script>
```